# Probability that one positive random variable is greater than another independent and identically distributed positive random variable

Tags: random-variable, ratio, iid, differences

Suppose I have the following random variables $X_{0} \sim f(x)$ and $X_{1} \sim f(x)$ are independent. I want to know the probability that $X_{0} > X_{1}$. So I think I want to find:

$$ P(X_{0}>X_{1}) = 1 - P(X_{0} \leq X_{1}) $$

So since these random variables are independent, this means we can write:

$$ P(X_{0} \leq X_{1}) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{x_{1}} f_{x}(x_{0})f_{x}(x_{1})dx_{0}dx_{1} $$

Since these are distributions, we know they are bounded, so Tonelli's theorem allows us to rewrite this an iterated integral:

$$ P(X_{0} \leq X_{1}) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[\int_{0}^{x_{1}} f_{x}(x_{0}) dx_{0} \right]f_{x}(x_{1})dx_{1} $$

So with repeated computer experiments, I found that if I draw $X_{0}$ and $X_{1}$ from independent identical distributions, I have:

$$ P(X_{0} \leq X_{1}) \leq \frac{1}{2} $$

I've done this for exponential, gamma, beta, laplace, rayleigh, rician, etc distributions and I always get the same thing.

Why is this? Is this some sort of theorem I don't know about, or is there some elementary manipulation I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: @Alex So then the first equation becomes $2 P(X_{0} \leq X_{1}) = 1 $ which means that $P(X_{0} \leq X_{1}) = \frac{1}{2}$. This could be an answer you know haha!

Comment: I am not providing answers until stackexchange sorts out their moderator mess! But I am glad my comment helped you :) https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5765/moderator-resignation

Comment: For independent random variables, _symmetry_ suggests that $P(X_0<X_1)$ must be the same as $P(X_0 > X_1)$, No? Now, $$P(X_0<X_1) + P(X_0 > X_1) + P(X_0=X_1) = 1,$$ the question boils down to what the value of $P(X_0=X_1)$ is. The answer is different for continuous and discrete random variables, and in the former case, we get that $$P(X_0 < X_1) = P(X_0 \leq X_1) = \frac 12.$$ Why this is so, I willl leave it to you to figure out.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Yes, this is because $P(X_{0} = X_{1}) = 0$ for continuous random variables. This is because $P(X=a) = P(a \leq X \leq a) = \int_{a}^{a} f_{X}(x)dx = 0$ But yes, your comment did help! Thank you!

Comment: @DilipSarwate So then I can write, $P(X_{0} \leq X_{1}) + P(X_{0} >X_{1}) = P(X_{0} \leq X_{1}) + P(X_{1} >X_{0}) = 2P(X_{0} \leq X_{1}) = 1 $ which gives us our answer, correct?